# How do I import a local csv file into a cassandra container?

Tags: python, csv, docker, cassandra

I'm using docker on Windows 10 currently and I can't import a local csv file into the cassandra container, I run the following statement and it just shows me this error.
You already place the file in all possible paths and continue to throw the same error.

Sentence:

```
COPY practica.alumno(id_event,id_a,vehiculo,estatus,tipo) from 'c:\users\daniel\desktop\alumno.csv' with delimiter = ';' and header=true;
```

Error:

```
Failed to import 0 rows: IOError - Can't open 'c:\\users\\daniel\\desktop\\alumno.csv' for reading: no matching file found,  given up after 1 attempts
Processed: 0 rows; Rate:       0 rows/s; Avg. rate:       0 rows/s
0 rows imported from 0 files in 0.111 seconds (0 skipped).
```

Comment: `no matching file found,  given up after 1 attempts?` is the path  correct?

Comment: Docker doesn't have access to your windows filesystem. Did you try using a Volume mount?